# iOS: float16_t does not work on simulator

Tags: ios, floating-point

I tried to use the `float16_t` type in my iOS app to save memory space. It seems to work perfectly on device, but it does not build on simulator.

In the simulator build it fails with

> Unknown type name 'float16_t'; did you mean 'float_t'?

The `float16_t` seems to be defined in arm_neon.h.

Can this be fixed so that I can use that type on simulator?

Comment: I think you are wasting your time as the memory saved will be negligible.  Adding one image to the app will take more space than you saved by using this type.  Not to mention it looks like it's unsupported/difficult to use.

Comment: Maybe so. I guess I'll back out if I don't get a super duper suggestion within some time. I was a bit unclear, though. I want to save bandwidth on an external interface, not the internal memory. But you might be right. Maybe I'm wasting my time.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen types other than `float` and `double` used in any code, anywhere, in all my time coding.

Comment: No, of cause. It is a special type. The mantissa is reduced, but the exponent is the same. So it only reduces the resolution.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson: The exponent is also reduced.  `float16_t` (aka "half precision") uses a 5-bit exponent field (`float`, aka "single precision" uses an 8-bit exponent).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I will back out of this mess! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very obvious!

`float16_t` is declared in "arm_neon.h" means the type is strictly for ARM based CPU instructions (specifically ARM CPUs with supported NEON instruction set).

Till date, all iOS devices run on ARM based CPU. So your code is good when compiled for device (Though, possibly won't run in some very old iOS device with older ARM cpus without NEON).

However, iOS Simulator runs on a Mac, which is built on top of x86/x64 CPU architecture, not ARM. So ARM types simply don't work here.

I'm not sure why you do really want to work with some ARM NEON optimized data types like `float16_t`, when `float_t` works great, everywhere. But if you still want to use it and want your app to run everywhere, you should use conditional compilation directives to compile your code:

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    float_t x;
#else
    float16_t x;
#endif
```

Hope it helps.